# converting local site from php to html

Tags: php, html, header, localhost, footer

I am making a site for a client in which I am using php includes for header and footer and using wamp on my local machine. Lets say the client is not aware of wamp and all the technical stuff involved. Client wants to see the half done site and I dont have any online hosting which I can use to show him and can't send him the site because its using php.

I can manualy save each page as html and make some changes for it to run without local server, but if the site has many pages, that would take alot of time . Is there a quick way that I can use ??

Comment: This probably is possible, but it only pushes your problems into future. Why don't you solve your problem? You say that is a paying customer, so you want to earn money with this. You really act as a web programmer who does not have the means to setup a test page? Sorry, that won't fly. Go, get a web space, they are free these days!

Comment: arkascha tell me a good free hosting site please and thankyou.

Comment: Sorry, you might want to try a page called google for this. You should be able to find what you are looking for pretty fast. Try some search terms like "free web space".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar problems every now and then and usually I do one of the following:

- show a demo of the website myself on my laptop
- send screenshots

In my opinion sharing a half-baked website can make things worse as clients never know exactly where to click and why something was designed in a specific way.  Yes you can change pages to html but is it worth the effort to convert and test?

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment, this is _not_ an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found it :)

Use HTTrack website copier.